# Unable to insert images in a Note

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app

I'm trying to insert an image from my **Camera Roll** into a **Note**.
I've been able to do this in the past, but for some reason the option isn't showing anymore:

[image]

***How do I add photos to a Note?***

iOS 12, iPhone 6 Plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option has been moved down to the bar above your keyboard.

1. Press on the plus icon

[image: Press on the plus icon]

2. Choose Photo Library

[image: Result]